# Formulario de registro, comprobar dni y si usuario exite PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, if, else

haber si alguien me puede guiar.
Estoy haciendo un formulario de registro, en el cual tienen los campos típicos; pero los que necesito hacer comprobaciones antes de insertar el registro es de Username (email) y el nif.

Tengo un formulario que cuando le damos al submit llama a un AJAX

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $("#formuploadajax1").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax1"));
              formData.append("dato", "valor");
              //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
              $.ajax({
                  url: "incluCuenta/insertar-cliente.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false
              })
                  .done(function(res){
                      $("#mensaje").html(res);
                      toastr["info"]("Registro exitoso!", "Mensaje")
                      setTimeout(function () {
                             window.location.href = "login.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                         }, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
                  });
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Y luego por otra parte el `insertar-cliente.php`

```
<?php include "../conexion/conexion.php" ?>
<?php
 $nif = explode('-', $_POST['nif']);
 $numeros = $partes[0];
 $letra = strtoupper($partes[1]);
   if (substr("TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE",$numeros%23,1) == $letra)
    echo '<p>El DNI: '.$nif.' es correcto!</p>';
 else
    echo '<p>La letra introducida no es corrrecta!</p>';
 exit();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$movil = $_POST['movil'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$postal = $_POST['postal'];
$poblacion = $_POST['poblacion'];
$provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$fecha=date('y,m,d');



$results = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Fecha, Sexo, Nombre, Password, Username, Direccion, Postal, Poblacion, Provincia, Telefono, Movil, Dni, intestado) 
VALUES ('$fecha', '$sexo', '$name', '$pass', '$email', '$direccion', '$postal', '$poblacion', '$provincia', '$telefono', '$movil', '$nif', '1')";

 if ( !mysqli_query($mysqli, $results)) {
   die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error() );
 }
 mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Lo que necesito es que compruebe si Username existe en la bd y si el Nif es correcto.

Comment: Hola. lo que se me ocurre es que cuando haga submit, hagas un select de los usuarios registrados y que muestres los Username si conincide que haga ya existe o algo, y en cuanto al nif, que compruebe si los 6 caracteres son numeros, si es asi previamente creas un Array de letras, recorres ese array y si la posicion 7 del nif conicide con la letra de tu array pues que el OK no se si me hago entender ajaja

Comment: Cómo es el formato de los NIF? 6 números y el módulo 23 es la letra que corresponde?

Comment: Su formato es como el DNI, pero co la letra primero.

Comment: A ver, pero cómo es el formato que esperas. Es algo tipo `<letra>-<10 números>` o `<10 números>-<letra>`. En mi respuesta puse 6 números, guión, letra. Puedo cambiarla cuando respondas

Answer (score 0):

Como no puedo emular el llamado Ajax, lo sustituí con una promesa que se resuelve (o rechaza) luego de 1.5 segundos.

Definí un objeto con los usuarios:

```
var usuarios = {
    '665366-E': 'pedro@gmail.com',
    '357911-P': 'juan@gmail.com',
    '791816-H': 'diago@gmail.com',
    '699994-N': 'pablo@gmail.com',
    '427279-P': 'anita@gmail.com',
    '241585-Q': 'julia@gmail.com'
  };
```

De manera que estas promesas revisen si el NIF o el correo ya existen.

Básicamente, compruebo la disponibilidad con la función:

```
function isAvailable(nif, email) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      if (Object.keys(usuarios).indexOf(nif) !== -1 ||
        Object.values(usuarios).indexOf(email) !== -1) {
        resolve({
          disponible: false
        });
      } else {
        resolve({
          disponible: true
        });
      }
    }, 1500);
  });
}
```

Esta función acepta un `nif` y un `email`. Para comprobar si un nif existe la llamas como

```
isAvailable(nif, null) // en realidad el null es opcional
```

Y para comprobar un email la llamas como:

```
isAvailable(null, email)
```

La comprobación de la letra verificadora del NIF puedes hacerla en el front.

```
 var letras = 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE',

 var parteNumerica = parseInt(nif.split('-')[0], 10),
    letra = nif.split('-')[1].toUpperCase(),
    letraCorrecta = letras[parteNumerica % 23];

  if (letra !== letraCorrecta) {
    label.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    label.find('small').text('letra incorrecta');
    return;
  }
```

Cuando se quita el foco del input (o el mouse sale del fieldset), se ejecuta la comprobación.

El botón de enviar se activa al pasar el mouse sobre él cuando los dos inputs son válidos. Al enviar se repite la comprobación y retorna false si no se cumple.

Los inputs están sujetos a una expresión regular que, si no se cumple, informa que el valor ingresado no se ajusta al formato esperado (si quieres correos del tipo `nombre@hola.servidor.com` habrá que cambiar esa parte.

```js
var letras = 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE',
  usuarios = {
    '665366-E': 'pedro@gmail.com',
    '357911-P': 'juan@gmail.com',
    '791816-H': 'diago@gmail.com',
    '699994-N': 'pablo@gmail.com',
    '427279-P': 'anita@gmail.com',
    '241585-Q': 'julia@gmail.com'
  };

function isAvailable(nif, email) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      if (Object.keys(usuarios).indexOf(nif) !== -1 ||
        Object.values(usuarios).indexOf(email) !== -1) {
        resolve({
          disponible: false
        });
      } else {
        resolve({
          disponible: true
        });
      }
    }, 1500);
  });
}


function checkNif() {
  var $this = $('#nif');

  $this.val($this.val().trim().toUpperCase());

  var nif = $this.val(),
    label = $this.closest('label');

  if (!/^\d{6}-[A-Z]{1}$/.test(nif)) {
    label.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    label.find('small').text('Debe ingresar 6 dígitos, un guión y una letra');
    return;
  }
  var parteNumerica = parseInt(nif.split('-')[0], 10),
    letra = nif.split('-')[1].toUpperCase(),
    letraCorrecta = letras[parteNumerica % 23];

  if (letra !== letraCorrecta) {
    label.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    label.find('small').text('letra incorrecta');
    return;
  }

  label.removeClass('invalid')
    .find('small')
    .text('Comprobando disponibilidad');

  return isAvailable(nif, null).then((response) => {
    if (response.disponible === true) {
      label.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      label.find('small').text('NIF disponible');
    } else {
      label.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      label.find('small').text('NIF ya registrado');
    }
  });

}


function checkMail() {
  var $this = $('#correo');
  $this.val($this.val().trim().toLowerCase());

  var correo = $this.val().trim(),
    label = $this.closest('label');
  if (correo === '') {
    label.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    label.find('small').text('Correo es obligatorio');
    return false;
  } else if (!/^\w+@\w+\.\w+$/.test(correo)) {
    label.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    label.find('small').text('Correo inválido');
    return false;
  }
  label.removeClass('invalid')
    .find('small')
    .text('Comprobando disponibilidad');

  return isAvailable(null, correo).then((response) => {
    if (response.disponible === true) {
      label.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
      label.find('small').text('Correo disponible');
    } else {
      label.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
      label.find('small').text('Correo ya registrado');
    }
  });
}


function checkSubmit() {
  var $this = $('#enviar');
  if ($('#nif').closest('label').hasClass('valid') &&
    $('#correo').closest('label').hasClass('valid')) {
    $(this).removeClass('disabled').val('Enviar');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('disabled').val('Complete los campos para enviar');
    return false;
  }
}

jQuery('#nif').on('blur', checkNif);
jQuery('#correo').on('blur', checkMail);
jQuery('#field_nif label').on('mouseleave', checkNif);
jQuery('#field_correo label').on('mouseleave', checkMail);

jQuery('#enviar').on('click mouseover', checkSubmit);


jQuery('#formulario fieldset input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).closest('label')
    .removeClass('invalid')
    .removeClass('valid')
    .find('small')
    .text('');
});
```

```css
.invalid input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.valid input {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.invalid small {
  color: red;
}

.valid small {
  color: green;
}

#formulario fieldset {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-left: 0 none;
  border-right: 0 none;
  border-bottom-width: 0.5px;
  border-bottom-color: #CCC;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#formulario label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#formulario label span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

#formulario input {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

#formulario small {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

#formulario #enviar {
  width: 250px;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

#formulario #enviar.disabled {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formulario">
  <fieldset id="field_nif">
    <label for="nif">
<span>Nif:</span>
<input type="text" name="nif" id="nif" placeholder="ingrese su nif">
<small></small>
</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="field_correo">
    <label for="nombre">
<span>Correo</span>
<input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="ingrese su correo">
<small></small>
</label>

  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Complete los campos para enviar" class='disabled'>
</form>
```

---

## Implementación en PHP

Tu script de verificación `user_exists.php` sería algo como:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'test');

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
// capturar las entradas de POST o definirlas como '';
$nif   = isset($_POST['nif']) ? $_POST['nif'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT nif, email FROM usuarios WHERE nif=? OR email=?');

$sentencia->bind_param('ss', $nif, $email);

/* ejecutar la consulta */
$sentencia->execute();

/* almacenar el resultado */
$sentencia->store_result();

/* contar registros que calzan */
$disponible = ($sentencia->num_rows === 0);

/* cerrar la sentencia */
$sentencia->close();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(['disponible' => $disponible]);
```

Si la query no devuelve registros, el email **y** el nif no existen en la BBDD. Si devuelve registros, significa que el email **o** el nif ya existen.

La función `isAvailable` cambiaría a:

```
function isAvailable(nif, email) {

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'user_exists.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            nif: nif,
            email: email
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Esto es impresionante lo que has puesto aquí!!! pero como hago un while en php para que saque los mails y dni que hay en la bd?? Menuda currada, no se si capaz de ponerlo todo

Comment: Añadí a la respuesta cómo sería la implementación en PHP y cómo cambiaría la función `isAvailable`. En realidad sólo tienes que comprobar si existen, no necesitas un while. El script que **comprueba** es distinto al script que **inserta**. Sigue el principio de [separación de responsabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separaci%C3%B3n_de_intereses).

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, puedes hacerlo de dos maneras:

1) La primera es hacer un ajax donde le pases por parámetros dni y el usuario y luego lo recibas en el PHP para hacer las consulatas correspondientes para ver si existe algo como:

`"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM usuario WHERE dni = ".$dni`

2) La segunda es usar el mismo ajax pero hacer una consulta previa al **INSERT** para verificar si el dni existe, si no existe lo insertas y si existe retorna un error o un mensaje indicando de que ese dni existe.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(1) existe FROM usuario WHERE dni = ".$dni;
$resultado =  mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$existeDNI = $fila['existe'];

if($existeDNI = 0){

 $results = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Fecha, Sexo, Nombre, Password, Username, Direccion, Postal, Poblacion, Provincia, Telefono, Movil, Dni, intestado) 
VALUES ('$fecha', '$sexo', '$name', '$pass', '$email', '$direccion', '$postal', '$poblacion', '$provincia', '$telefono', '$movil', '$nif', '1')";

 if ( !mysqli_query($mysqli, $results)) {
   die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error() );
 }

}else{
  Aquí retornas el error al ajax
}
```

Comment: Esto probando tu opción, me parece algo más sencilla para mi, pero lo estoy haciendo con el Username en lugar de con el DNI. Pero me devuelve error :S

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!, creo que la forma mas sencilla de hacerlo es con un count, a mi no me ha dado problemas en ninguno de mis proyectos, lo que hará el count sera hacer una query al servidor a través de php para comprobar cuantos elementos hay en la tabla que definas.

**Comprobar usuario:**

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$checkuser = "SELECT COUNT(*) numero FROM Usuarios WHERE name = '$name';";

$test = $conn->query($checkuser);
$test_f = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test);

if($test_f['numero'] === "1")
   {
    echo "Este nombre de usuario ya está registrado.";
   }
 else
    {
     echo "Este nombre de usuario no está registrado, prosigue con el registro";
        }

//numero = 0: No hay usuarios registrados con ese nombre.
//numero = 1: Hay un usuario con ese nombre, no se puede completar el registro.
//numero = mas de uno: Tienes varios usuarios con el mismo nombre (con este método no debería de pasar).
```

Para comprobar cualquier otro tipo de dato es exactamente el mismo proceso, solo que cambiando `name` por cualquier otro dato.

Por ejemplo, un email:

**Comprobar email:**

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$checkuser = "SELECT COUNT(*) numero FROM Usuarios WHERE name = '$email';";

$test = $conn->query($checkuser);
$test_f = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test);

if($test_f['numero'] === "1")
   {
    echo "Este nombre de usuario ya está registrado.";
   }
 else
    {
     echo "Este nombre de usuario no está registrado, prosigue con el registro";
        }

//numero = 0: No hay usuarios registrados con ese nombre.
//numero = 1: Hay un usuario con ese nombre, no se puede completar el registro.
//numero = mas de uno: Tienes varios usuarios con el mismo nombre (con este método no debería de pasar).
```

Para el DNI seguiría el mismo proceso, creando una nueva variable `$dni = $_POST['dni'];` y cambiando los parámetros del COUNT.

Un saludo, gracias por tu pregunta :)